# Create a "for" loop with Mustache.js templating system

Tags: javascript, templates, loops, mustache

I'd like to create a "for" loop in my Mustache.js template.

I'd like to do something like that:

```
<ol>
    {{for $i = 0; $i < $steps; $i++}}
    <li {{$i == $active}}class="active"{{/$i}}></li>
    {{/for}}
</ol>
```

With the variable `$steps = 5` and `$active = 2` for example

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about running PHP code and have it templated by mustache?

Comment: This is just an example to explain what I need, and now I want to know how to do it using Mustache.js

Comment: But Mustache templates javascript objects..shouldn't you do the logic in javascript? There's nothing in the above code I see that templates anything.

Comment: So I have to handle my DOM directly in my js file?